# Configuring remote access via slow inet in 2020?

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I'm in a rural area with a 3Mbps wireless link that works great for remote desktop access to Windows 10 systems, but is completely saturated by `xrdp` to a remote Ubuntu 18.04 system, even when the only window open is a terminal scrolling text.

I've tried following various "how-tos" configuring the Ubuntu system with alternate window managers purporting to solve this but everything seems either to break the `xrdp` function or be equally slow.  Moreover, since the history of this goes back a decade or more, there are enormous numbers of obsolete fixes that should not be followed in 2020.

Any advice?

PS: My impression is that `xrdp` isn't being maintained properly and that I may have to end up paying for something that is.  That's fine by me as trying to navigate configuration Hell isn't my idea of a fun time.  But if I'm going to pay, I rather insist on being assured it is going to be approximately as fast as my Windows 10 RDP.